# Use Spring multiDataSource in chaos

Tags: java, spring, datasource

In my project, I want method A,B use database1, and all other methods use database2.
Now I write like this in controller

```
DataSourceHolder.putDataSource("db1");
String code = methodA();//for get some
DataSourceHolder.putDataSource("db2");
methodC(code);
...
DataSourceHolder.putDataSource("db1");
methodB(code);//for set some
DataSourceHolder.putDataSource("db2");
```

In most cases, it runs normally. But while many people visit my webset, it may use wrong dataSource. Some data can not be saved or updated.

Comment: does not seem very threadsafe

Comment: so, how should i do?

Comment: Use ThreadLocal in DataSourceHolder to store dataSource

Comment: Where is that `DataSourceHolder` class defined, is it similar to the one in [this post?](http://www.roytuts.com/define-multiple-datasources-in-spring/)